# Get start and end of string comparison

Tags: c#, string-comparison

I'm trying to create some sort of string-based diff algorithm on my own.
What I'm doing is: I'm iterating through every paragraph in my textdocument, comparing them both.

Now what I'm struggling with is the comparison start and end of both strings.

Consider having the two strings:

`This is a test-text.`

`This is a very long test-text.`

This means there's a change of 10 characters (9 text, 1 whitespace) in the second line (`'very long '`).

These characters should be highlighted accordingly. I've already come up with the solution of finding the start of the string-differences (say: index n is where the differences start):

`int diffIndexStart = localText.Zip(serverText, (c1, c2) => c1 == c2).TakeWhile(b => b).Count();`

Now how can I detect when the string matches again, so I can stop highlighting there, instead of highlighting the rest of the row (starting with `diffIndexStart`).

There's also another issue: What's when there are multiple changes within one line, let's say:

`This is a test-text.`

`This, apparently, is a very long test-text.`

Now I've got two changes: `, apparently,` and `very long`.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking at the common [Longest Common Subsequence (LCS) problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem). There are numerous papers on that (the Wikipedia page gives some links as a start), several common approaches are highlighted in Wiki already.

Comment: Is this an answer or comment? And I think It's more related to [Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance)

Comment: Do you claim my answer does not give a direction to work in? Or did you expect to see an cheap freelancer-style "this code piece works" non-answer?

Comment: `And I think It's more related to Levenshtein distance` Yes and no - OP does speak only of insertions here, at least in examples.